# ffmpeg silenceremove - hear what bits are removed

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

ffmpeg silenceremove is pretty cool. im loving it. i can trim 3 second silences to 2 seconds and reduce a 1.5 hour file of spoken audio down 3 or 4 minutes (depending on the speaker).

once in a while I do hear my choice for stop_threshold (ie-40dB on audio only analog file) does cause the end of a word to be clipped, just here and there when the speaker trails off softly at the end of the word.

is there any way to output what is trimmed to a file? so I can listen to it and get an idea of just how often this word clipping happens?

thanks!